# Mongodb upgrade from 3.0 to 3.2

Tags: mongodb, upgrade

I have upgraded the mongodb from 3.0.15 to 3.2

**mongodb3.0.15 Configuration :**

Three shards

Three config servers

**mongodb3.2 Configuration :**

Three shards

Three config servers
  No replica sets

I just upgraded the mongodb to 3.2
Started the mongo services by pointing it to the 3.2 binaries

**Mongo Script:**

mongod --keyFile C:\mongoConfigData\key --configsvr  --dbpath C:\mongoConfigData/configdb1 --port 27019 --storageEngine wiredTiger

mongod --keyFile C:\mongoConfigData\key --configsvr  --dbpath C:\mongoConfigData/configdb2 --port 27020 --storageEngine wiredTiger

mongod --keyFile C:\mongoConfigData\key --configsvr  --dbpath C:\mongoConfigData/configdb3 --port 27021 --storageEngine wiredTiger

mongos --keyFile C:\mongoConfigData\key  --configdb 127.0.0.1:27019,127.0.0.1:27020,127.0.0.1:27021

mongod --keyFile C:\mongoConfigData\key  --config C:\mongoConfigData\mongod.config --dbpath e:\data --storageEngine wiredTiger --wiredTigerJournalCompressor zlib --wiredTigerCollectionBlockCompressor zlib --wiredTigerCacheSizeGB 7 --port 27010

mongod --keyFile C:\mongoConfigData\key --config C:\mongoConfigData\mongod.config --dbpath f:\data --storageEngine wiredTiger --wiredTigerJournalCompressor zlib --wiredTigerCollectionBlockCompressor zlib --wiredTigerCacheSizeGB 7  --port 27011

mongod --keyFile C:\mongoConfigData\key --config C:\mongoConfigData\mongod.config --dbpath g:\data --storageEngine wiredTiger --wiredTigerJournalCompressor zlib --wiredTigerCollectionBlockCompressor zlib --wiredTigerCacheSizeGB 7  --port 27012

But after the upgrade i could see that the sharding has gone for toss.
Now when i try to view the shards it says that the collection is not sharded.
Let me know if i am missing anything.

Answer (score -1):

As per MongoDB documentation [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.2-upgrade/) **To Upgrade a Replica Set to 3.2**, All replica set members must be running version 3.0 before you can upgrade them to version 3.2. To upgrade a replica set from an earlier MongoDB version, upgrade [all members of the replica set to the latest 3.0-series release](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/release-notes/3.0-upgrade/) first, and then follow the procedure to upgrade from MongoDB 3.0 to 3.2.

**Upgrade Binaries**

You can upgrade from MongoDB 3.0 to 3.2 using a `rolling` upgrade to minimize downtime by upgrading the members individually while the other members are available:

Avoid reconfiguring replica sets that contain members of different MongoDB versions as validation rules may differ across MongoDB versions.

**Upgrade secondary members of the replica set**

Upgrade the [secondary](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-members/#replica-set-secondary-members) members of the replica set one at a time:

1. Shut down the  [mongod](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongod/#bin.mongod) instance and replace the 3.0 binary with the 3.2
   binary.
2. Restart the member and wait for the member to recover to **SECONDARY**
   state before upgrading the next secondary member. To check the
   member’s state, issue  [rs.status()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/rs.status/#rs.status) in the [mongo](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongo/#bin.mongo) shell.

**Step down the replica set primary**

Connect a [mongo](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongo/#bin.mongo) shell to the primary and use [rs.stepDown()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/rs.stepDown/#rs.stepDown) to step down the primary and force an election of a new primary:

**Upgrade the primary**

When  [rs.status()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/rs.status/#rs.status) shows that the primary has stepped down and another member has assumed PRIMARY state, upgrade the stepped-down primary:

1. Shut down the stepped-down primary and replace the mongod binary
   with the 3.2 binary.
2. Restart.

> **Note :** 
>   MongoDB 3.2 generates core dumps on some mongod failures. For
>   production environments, you may prefer to turn off core dumps for the
>   operating system, if not already.